# "message": "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, api, ssl, .net-core

I integrate 3rd party API in my API. That time got error. Maybe this is SSL connection issue.

```
"data": {
"message": "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.",
"data": {},
"innerException": {
  "ClassName": "System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException",
  "Message": "Authentication failed, see inner exception.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "ClassName": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",
    "Message": "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": null,
    "HResult": -2147467259,
    "Source": null,
    "WatsonBuckets": null,
    "NativeErrorCode": -2146893018
  },
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233087,
  "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
},
"stackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\r\n   at weplay.api.Helpers.SexyBaccarat_Game.SexyBaccarat.SexyBaccaratHelpers.SexyBaccarateRegisterAsync(ProfileRequest request) in E:\\Yudiz\\Projects\\W\\WeplayDevOps\\weplay.api\\Helpers\\SexyBaccarat_Game\\SexyBaccarat\\SexyBaccaratHelpers.cs:line 125",
"helpLink": null,
"source": "System.Net.Http",
"hResult": -2146233087}
```

and API code is

```
using (var SB_helper = new SBHelpers(Connection))
            {
                using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
                {
                    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
                    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
                    //send request
                    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                    {
                        string bodyParameter = $"cert={SBConst.Cert}&agentId={SBConst.AgentId}&userId={SBConst.UserNamePrefix + request.UserId}&currency={request.Currency}&betLimit={request.BetLimit}&language={request.Language}";
                        var content = new StringContent(bodyParameter, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"{SBConst.APIURL}{SBConst.Method.CreateMember}", content);
                        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        dynamic responseOk = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This error got on live server. But on **localhost** and **windows 10** that is working fine.

Anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: On which framework version are you? I would expect you can set the SecurityProtocol without that hack.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: 'The message received was unexpected or badly formatted' can you shiff auth request/response with WireShark or Fiddler?

Comment: dotnet core 2.0 @rene

Comment: full error is there @renat

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the certificates, either the certs on the server you deployed to or with the certs you receive once deplloyed. Maybe ignoring what is thrown at you in the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback event isn't the best approach to diagnose this. Log the errors that are in that errors parameter and/or the certs that are offered. One of those questions might help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22The+message+received+was+unexpected+or+badly+formatted%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0

Comment: yes @KrivitskiyGrigoriy, I used that. Same as Postman output shown there.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue, we are facing the same issue

Comment: you need to upgrade server.

Comment: upgrade to which one?